# How to redirect page to another activity?

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a simple quiz application. It has six fragment and a score page which hold number of correct and wrong answers. In each fragment there is a question, radio-button for answers and a 'submit' (btn1) button. In this button answer is checked, it works until here  but when I write code in onClick method to move another page, it went something wrong. What would be the my mistake?

```
public class Question1 extends Fragment {

RadioButton q1a2;
Button btn1;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question1, null);
    return v;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    q1a2 = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.q1a2);
    btn1 =(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();



            if(q1a2.isChecked()){

                editor.putInt("answer_value", 1);

            }else{
                editor.putInt("answer_value", 0);

            }


            editor.commit();

            Intent q1 = new Intent(Question1.this.getActivity(), Question2.class);
            startActivity(q1);

        }


    });



}
```

}

could be a mistake in manifest.xml ?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pc.quizapplicationproject">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>


</activity>


    <activity android:name=".Register"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainQuizActivity">
            <activity android:name=".Question1"/>
            <activity android:name=".Question2"/>




        </activity>





    <activity android:name="com.example.pc.quizapplicationproject.Score" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you only need activity context for opening a new activity.

```
Intent q1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Question2.class);
            startActivity(q1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get reference of button in `onCreateView(){`

Like this

```
btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b tn1);
```

And I also suggest you to get reference of radio button in onCreateView()

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the getview()

```
btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Question1.this, Question2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```